# Is there a reason to create more than one Sector in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

The only reason to create another Sector, that our empire found so far, is that unconnected systems can't be added to an existing Sector.

Are there any other reasons/advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The impossibilty to add a colony to a sector due to distance is the main reason at the moment.

Additionaly:
You can specialize sectors and set taxes.

You might want to create a sector specialized in research, another in finance, another in mineral production etc.

You mgiht also want to create a builder sector, where new colonies land, which has lots of resources and no taxes to allow for quick growth and then switch the system to another sector.

Comment: also, the number of colonized planets per sector seems to be related to the growing of factions which demand independence for their sector and one way to mitigate this is splitting sectors into smaller ones so that these factions gain less traction and can be handled more easily (costing you less diplomatic capital). "good old" divide and conquer if you will.

Answer (score 6):

As someone already mentioned in a comment, another reason is to more easily manage the factions/reduce the potential damage of a sector breaking away.

Having a fairly large sector with important planets break away can totally ruin your empire. Having multiple smaller sectors mitigates that risk

Answer (score 2):

A third reason, unless the UI is faking me out, is that each sector has an energy/mining cap (which in my last game at least was equal to my main cap).  If you're running a surplus of energy credits and/or mining credits (and can spare the influence to get 75% of it later), you can create a 2nd or 3rd sector and mainly just use it as a dumping ground for resources until you need to cash it in.  (This assumes you don't see anything e.g. in [How should I spend energy credits?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294808/how-should-i-spend-energy-credits) that you'd rather use your excess for)

Answer (score 1):

Each sector has its own governor. So when you have more sectors, you need more governors, but you can also pick governors with perks which are especially beneficial for a given sector.

For example, when a sector has a lot of new colonies, you might want one with "Architectural Sense" and/or "Environmental Engineer" to save on development cost. When a sector consists of colonies annexed from a slave species, you want one with "Iron Fist".